# Calling Large Shapefiles into R, 2 GB polygon layer, rgdal

Tags: r, rstudio, shapefile, rgdal, bigdata

I'm attempting to open a **shapefile** in R using rgdal.  my code is simply:

```
shp <- readOGR("D:/Documents/EPA/Groundwater_Wells/R Work", "us_blocks_2010")
```

The error message I receive is:

**Error: C stack usage  81982167 is too close to the limit**

The shapefile I'm attempting to open is 2.09 GB.  I am working with 32 GB of RAM on a 64 bit version of windows 10 and using R Studio 64 bit so this size should not be an issue according to (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Memory-limits.html).  This is a really large polygon dataset with about 11 million polygons representing all Census blocks in the United States.  My question is: Is there a way to manipulate the maximum size that my R session can handle? or, is there a format, such as converting to a geopackage that will allow me to more efficiently use this data? Ultimately I would like to be able to convert it back into a format usable with ArcGIS such as a geodatabase but if I can work with the data more efficiently in a different format that only works in R, that's fine too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but you could see the `st_read` function from the `sf` package

Comment: Did you figure out a solution? I'm having a similar problem